# Can we install Other Linux softwares in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, kali-linux

I am a networking Student and just moved to `Kali Linux`. For my University work I need some software like `ns2/ns3`. I know we can install them in `Ubuntu`.

My Question is Can we install `ns3` and `ns2` in `Kali Linux`.

And other software which are available in Ubuntu?

If not then what is the reason behind it. While `Ubuntu` and `Kali` both are Linux versions.

If yes then procedure will be same like `Ubuntu` or will be different

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you don't have the software in your repositories (I.e. apt-get install doesn't have it) is to go to the source to see if they offer downloads. If you see it's available for other versions but not strictly yours, Kali is closest to Debian.

Some programs are just written for different OS/DEs. Linux is just the kernel, meaning it handles the way high level functionality like halting and reaching the boot loader and stuff. There's other considerations (like "is the user using init or SysV" or a ton of other stuff) that those who made the programmers have to take into account.

It's also a possibility that those who run Kali's repos just haven't added the software.

Depending on what ns2/ns3 you mean, maybe download the tarball and install it from there? https://www.nsnam.org/releases
This may be slightly more intimidating for new users but installation from source generally isn't more than a few steps.

Technically you can add the /etc/apt/sources.list contents from Ubuntu to Kali to get Kali to install Ubuntu software but that's honestly such a terrible idea I shouldn't have even mentioned it.